# Can we able to post blog on another Wordpress blogsite?

Tags: multisite

I am relatively new to Wordpress.

When we check techcrunch.com which is built on Wordpress platform, they have few official bloggers and tons of comment posters which is usually authenticated through facebook.

How do a Wordpress Blogging site manage other Bloggers to Blog / Post blog on their Blogging site ?

Whether Wordpress allows an Admin User and non-admin users to blog on a Website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Comment: While the link is perfectly on topic, lone link is not considered a very good answer (what if it dies? etc). Please try to include at least some summary information in your answer.

Comment: @Kevin, thank you. I read Summary of Roles, i assume bloggers in Techcrunch could be Editor Role.

Comment: @Rarst I really doubt the Codec is going anywhere.

Comment: @Kevin Codex might not, but link very well might. What if domain changes? What if URL structure is different? And so on.

Comment: @Rarst, I stand on your question too ..!! For me your question is too advanced, But its really a worth to ask !! But the posted link is very much useful from the beginners point !!